# How do I specify only running instances in Google's Python API client?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

I am building a list of gcloud instances using the Python API.

These are the commands that pull the info from GCP on the servers:

```
project_id = 'company1'
zone = 'us-east1-b'
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
result = compute.instances().list(project=project_id, zone=zone).execute()
```

When I run the script it pulls info for ALL the servers in the projects both running and stopped.

How can I specify that I only want to get the running servers using these commands? Can I specify a `status=running` somewhere in those commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the API documentation for [list()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instances.html#list), notice the parameter `filter=None`. To filter the output, specify a filter.

More details about filers are [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).

To filter on running instances, use the filter `status=running`

```
result = compute.instances().list(project=project_id, zone=zone, filter='status=running').execute()
```

Comment: OK that's great. Thank you for the info!